# how to make a nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter, object

I'm learning how to make nested arrays, following the json response that I made.

Comment: call `db_paket_id()` inside `db_paket`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_merge` to merge two or more arrays.
In your case:

```
$res = [
    'data' => array_merge(
        $this->M_wilayah->db_paket($origin,$destinasi),
        ['harga' => $this->M_wilayah->db_paket_id($origin,$destinasi)]
    )
];
```

Answer (score 0):

There's `array_merge function` to combine arrays, then you can make an array of array:

```
$res = [
    'data' => array_merge(
        $this->M_wilayah->db_paket($origin, $destinasi),
        ['harga' => $this->M_wilayah->db_paket_id($origin, $destinasi)]
 )
];
```

And you must have an json as follow:

```
[
    { "data": {
            "id_origin": "1",
            "origin": "jakarta raya",
            "id_destinasi": "7",
            "destinasi": "DKI Jakarta, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Tanah Abang, Bendungan Hilir, 10210",
            "harga": {
                "reguler": "8500",
                "nextday": "15000"
            }
        }    
    },
    { "data": {
            "id_origin": "2",
            "origin": "another origin",
            "id_destinasi": "8",
            "destinasi": " another data like DKI Jakarta, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Tanah Abang, Bendungan Hilir, 10210",
            "harga": {
                "reguler": "8500",
                "nextday": "15000"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

use db_paket_id in db_paket methods 
or

```
$res['data']['harga'] = $this->M_wilayah->db_paket_id($origin, $destinasi);
```